# Finding index of a Fibonacci number: any mathematical solution possible?

Tags: algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

The problem:

> ```
>                Given a Fibonacci number,find its index.
> ```

I am aware of the standard solution '**generate-hash-find**'. I am just curious if there is some inverse system of matrix exponentiation or some other mathematical method that gives the solution.

Comment: $\lceil 1+\log_{\phi}(x)\rceil$ should be a good starting point.

Comment: To expand a bit on J.M.'s comment, the idea is to (1) find an $n$ such that $F_n \leq x \leq F_{n+k}$ for some small $k$ - i.e. you want your first guess to be good - (2) use the matrix multiplication method to compute $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ and (3) if you haven't hit $x$ yet, then just keep computing $F_{n+2},F_{n+3},\ldots, F_{n+k}$ until you hit $x$

Comment: [In any event...](http://tinyurl.com/24pamsg)

Comment: @J.M. As for the downvote on this question: I downvoted it, because I expect the asker to do some rudimentary research before posting a question. A question about Fibonacci numbers that can be answered within 2 minutes by looking up the term "Fibonacci number" on Wikipedia is, in my mind, a bad question. I have flagged your comment by the way.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not

Answer (score 12):

From wikipedia:
"Similarly, if we already know that the number F is a Fibonacci number, we can determine its index within the sequence by

> $$n = \bigg\lfloor \log_\varphi \left(F\cdot\sqrt{5} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\bigg\rfloor.$$

Comment: Do you have a link? There are two different indices that both have the value of 1, so there can't be any formula that doesn't deal with that special case.

Answer (score 2):

Using this [other my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not/14872#14872)
Using integers only, I would use [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search). Certainly you can compute $F_n$ only with integers, the simplest way is matrix exponentiation. Using Binary Search you can find numbers ``near'' your number $x$ and you will find $x = F_n$ (and $n$). I suppose this method is generic for anything monotone you can compute fast. To initiliaze the binary search, just keep doubling $ F_{2n} $

Binary search allows you to search for a number x in a sorted "array" F[] (in the programming sense). Use this method to search for your number. When you need F[n] just compute $F_n$. This will work because the sequence is strictly increasing except for the initial 1,1.