# How many numbers are in the Fibonacci sequence below a given threshold?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Assuming I'm asked to generate Fibonacci numbers up to N, how many numbers will I generate? I'm looking for the count of Fibonacci numbers up to N, not the Nth number.

So, as an example, if I generate Fibonacci numbers up to 25, I will generate:

- 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
- that's 8 numbers

How do I calculate this mathematically for an arbitrary "n"?

Comment: If you use the closed-form expression for the Fibonacci numbers it should be easy enough.

Comment: Let's clarify: you're asking how many numbers less than or equal to a given number are Fibonacci?

Comment: Maybe you could look up the formula called Binet's Formula.

Comment: With regards to the closed-form expression, such a formula you can see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Binet's formula,

$$F_n=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n})$$

where $\phi=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$ is the golden ratio, is a closed-form expression for the Fibonacci numbers. See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011) for a few proofs.

As for counting how many Fibonacci numbers are there that are less than or equal to a given number $n$, one can derive an estimate from Binet's formula. The second term in the formula can be ignored for large enough $n$, so

$$F_n\approx\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Solving for $n$ here gives

$$n=\frac{\log\,F_n+\frac12\log\,5}{\log\,\phi}$$

Taking the floor of that gives a reasonable estimate; that is, the expression

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\log\,n+\frac12\log\,5}{\log\,\phi}\right\rfloor$$

can be used to estimate the number of Fibonacci numbers $\le n$. This is inaccurate for small $n$, but does better for large $n$.

---

It turns out that by adding a fudge term of $\frac12$ to $n$, the false positives of the previous formula disappear. (Well, at least in the range I tested.) Thus,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{\log\left(n+\frac12\right)+\frac12\log\,5}{\log\,\phi}\right\rfloor$$

gives better results.

Comment: Nicely put. This is essentially mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding.

Comment: Your second $\phi$ should be $1-\phi=\psi$

Comment: @Ross, $(-\phi)^{-1}$ is the same as $\psi = 1-\phi$.

Comment: The caveat of the old formula is that there are a few false positives even with large $n$. For $21 < n < 5000$, the floored formula is off for $n=34, 123, 356, 966, 2563$. Adding $\frac12$ fixes that, but I have to wonder if there's still a chance of false positives...

Comment: @Ross: but I like the form that shows off $\phi$ nicely... ;)

Comment: One caveat of this solution is that for large $n$ you may need a very good approximation of $\phi$.

Comment: Agreed, @lhf. Now that you mention it, I suddenly remembered [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999)...

Comment: @J.M.:missed the negative sign in the exponent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains everything!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we take $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$, for all $n\geq 0$, the value of the $F_n$ is the nearest integer to $\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

So, the number of Fibonnaci numbers less than $N$ is the number of $n\geq 0$ such that:

$$ \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}} \leq N+\frac{1}{2}$$

Solving this, we see that $n \leq \log_\phi(\sqrt{5}(N+\frac{1}{2}))$.  That means that the number of $n$ is:

$$1+\lfloor{\log_\phi(\sqrt{5}(N+\frac{1}{2}))}\rfloor$$

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will be able to find a closed-form formula for the number of Fibonacci numbers less than $N$ - if you had chosen $N = 26$ instead of $N = 25$, you would have gotten the same answer, but if you had set $N = 34$, the answer would have suddenly jumped to $9$. As has been suggested before, you can use Binet's formula:

nth Fibonacci number $F_n= (\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n})/(\sqrt 5)$ where $\phi = (1 + (\sqrt 5))/2$

Simply plug in values of $n$ until $F_n > N$; then the number you are looking for is $n-1$.

Comment: We can get explicit formula using $\log$ and floor (or nearest integer) functions.

Comment: The second $\phi$ should be $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  This is less than $1$ in absolute value and can be ignored for reasonable $n$

Comment: I corrected the answer according to Binet's formula: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html