# How do I apply the $\pm4$ part of the equation $5F_n^2\pm~4=L_n^2$ without knowing $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to test a great many numbers $a^3+b^3$ to see if any of them are Fibonacci using the formula
$$a^3+b^3=F_n \iff 5(a^3+b^3)^2\pm~4=L_n^2$$
I want to make my search more efficient by having some way of selecting one term, $+4$ or $-4$, that is the one more likely to produce a perfect square, and exclude the other one on the basis that it could never make a perfect square, instead of resorting to trial and error as I have been. What trick can I use to accomplish this?

Edit: I have since abandoned both the five-times-square test (initially in favor of the Mobius test, [referred to in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823247), which was faster) and also the looping through pairs of cubes (in favor of looping through Fibonacci indices instead). However, the answers below are helpful from a hypothetical-theoretical standpoint.

Comment: How is that any faster than just checking if $x$ is a Fibonacci number directly?

Comment: @vonbrand If $x$ were something specific, say $a^3+b^3$, and I were stepping through each pair of cubes in turn, it could get very inefficient to check both possible scenarios if I were checking a whole bunch of them, which I am.

Comment: @vonbrand also these numbers are very large, so I can't just look them up in a table or something.

Comment: @vonbrand I have edited my question to reflect this detail.

Comment: Related: MSE 789588 <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789588/conjecture-theres-only-one-fibonacci-number-that-is-the-sum-of-two-cubes>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to check if $F$ is a fibonacci number.

One simple check you can do to cut down your perfect square check computations is to consider $r = F \mod 7$.

For some $r$ you can ignore one of $5F^2 \pm 4$ as that leaves a remainder which cannot lead to a perfect square (quadratic non-residue)

$r = 0$, you can ignore $5F^2 - 4$

$r = 2$, you can ignore $5F^2 + 4$

$r = 3$, you can ignore $5F^2 - 4$

etc.

For other $r$ ($r=1$ and $r=6$), you consider both $5F^2 \pm 4$

You  might be able to choose numbers other than $7$ to cut it down even more, or have a nested if with a series of such remainders...

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to solve $F_n = a^3 + b^3$ (for instance in order to investigate
[MSE question 
 789588](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789588)) then it's much more efficient to loop over $n$ than over
$a$ and $b$.  Thanks to the factorization $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$
it's enough to check for each solution of $xy=F_n$ whether
$3(4x-y^2)$ is a square, since that's the criterion for 
$(x, y) = (a^2-ab+b^2, a+b)$ [the point is that  $4x-y^2 = 3(a-b)^2$].
I did this for all $n \leq 300$ using 
[this
table of Fibonacci factorizations](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html#100)
(discarding the 100 values of $n$ for which $F_n\bmod 9 \in \{3,4,5,6\}$,
since such a number can never be the sum of two cubes).
This took only ~30 seconds in **gp**, even though 
some candidates $F_n$ in this range have more than a million factors.
Not surprisingly I found that in this range the only solutions of 
$F_n = a^3 + b^3$ (with the integers $a,b$ not necessarily positive)
are the known $F_3 = 2 = 1^3 + 1^3$ and $F_6 = 8 = 2^3 + 0^3 = 0^3 + 2^3$.

Comment: Technically $0$ is not a _positive_ cube. Did I mention that I was checking for sums of two positive cubes?

Comment: The technique I suggested will find all solutions, whether
positive, zero, or negative, with little more effort than
just finding the positive ones.  Hence the parenthetical remark
"(with the integers $a,b$ not necessarily positive)".  If for
whatever reason we're interested only in positive $a,b$
(as in question 789588) then it's easy to discard the others 
once we've found the full list of integer solutions.