# $8$ is the only fibonacci number who's a cube (except $1$)

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

[What's special about this number](https://erich-friedman.github.io/numbers.html) states $8$ to be the largest fibonacci number who's also a cube (the third power of some integer). So it's basically the only one beacuse forget about $1$.

I Personally think $8$ can do better than that (e.g, it's the smallest order of a [hamiltonian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hamiltonian_group&redirect=no) - [the quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group)) but we'll leave that for now.

I've searched for a proof here and surprisingly couldn't find one (maybe I haven't searched good enough?), so I would be curious to learn here why is that so.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be trivial.  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1624/is-8-the-largest-cube-in-fibonacci-sequence) is a discussion.

Comment: Nitpick: also $0$, $-1$, and $-8$ are cubes, but people usually forget about the zeroeth and negative places. (which is disappointing; I find $0,1$ a nicer place to start than $1,1$)

Comment: @lulu Huh, and I innocently thought that running possibilities for cubic residues will do... Thanks for the reference

Comment: If you are interested in one cube for Fibonacci, you might also like [two cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789588/conjecture-only-one-fibonacci-number-is-the-sum-of-two-cubes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer, together with references has been given on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1624/is-8-the-largest-cube-in-fibonacci-sequence). In particular, [this paper](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/fibo.pdf) by Burgeaud et al. shows that 1, 8, and 144 are the only perfect powers in the Fibonacci sequence, which in particular implies that 8 is the largest cube.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fibonacci_number&oldid=775078705#Fibonacci_primes) references a proof that $8$ and $144$ are the only perfect powers in the sequence of Fibonacci numbers. (presumably, restricting to $a^b$ with $a,b > 1$)