# How do you determine if a number is a even Fibonacci number or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Rather than computing out the whole Fibonacci sequence and check if $n$ is even and in there, is there a more straightforward way to compute if $n$ is a even Fibonacci number?

Comment: See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n^\text {th} $ Fibonacci number is given by $$ F_n=\frac {\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt {5}}, $$ where $\phi $ is the golden ratio. If your number is $x $, then you could try $$\frac {\cosh^{-1}(\sqrt {5}x/2)}{\ln\phi}.$$ If this is an even integer, then $x $ is a Fibonacci number. Also if $$\frac {\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt {5}x/2)}{\ln\phi}$$ is odd.

Comment: It's definitely true, but I don't think that using of golden ratio is a good idea. In my opinion, question related to very big numbers (small numbers we can find in a table or check OEIS for its), and you should use only integer operations (even if it's integer square root)

Comment: You are saying integer square roots should not be used?

Comment: of course no, it's my awful English. I want to say that $\sqrt5$ and $\ln\phi$ should not be used

Answer (score 0):

**[Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio):** $~F_n~\simeq~\dfrac{\phi^n}{\sqrt5}$

Comment: Improve your wiki skills! )