# How to check if a number is present in the series $1, 7, 25, 63, 129, 231...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check if a number is present in the series $1, 7, 25, 63, 129, 231...$?

The nth term of the series is $(2  n + 1) (2n^2 + 2 n + 3) / 3$.

if $N = 7$, then it is present in the series.

Comment: I don't know exactly what sort of answer you *expect* to be getting... you could expand this out as a cubic and solve the cubic and check to see if the solution is an integer.  If it is, then the number is present in the series.  It will be [quite ugly though](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+y%3D%282x%2B1%29%282x%5E2%2B2x%2B3%29%2F3).

Comment: reminds me of [how to check if a number is Fibonacci](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we seek an $n$ solving $O_n=N$, with $n$th centered octahedral number$$O_n:=\frac13(2n+1)(2n^2+2n+3)\in(\tfrac16(2n)^3,\,\tfrac16(2n+1)^3).$$Since $(2n)^3\le6N\le(2n+1)^3$, there's at most one candidate $n$ to check.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sequence [A001845](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C7%2C25%2C63%2C129%2C231&sort=&language=german&go=Suche) giving the centered octahedral numbers (crystal ball sequence for cubic lattice). For smaller numbers you can simply check the given list there.

Of course, with a formula at hand, you can simply 
solve the equation
$$
(2n+1)(2n^2+2n+3)/3=k
$$
for $n$ and see if it has an integral solution. For example, take $k=20$. The formula shows that we need $n<2$. But for $n=0,1$ it is false. So first, estimate $n$, and then check for those $n$.

Comment: Surely the OP is looking for a way other than cross referencing a table...

Comment: I didn't expected this type of answer.I wanted a formula instead.

Answer (score 0):

$$6N=8n^3+12n^2+16n+6\\=(2n+1)^3+5(2n+1)$$
Let $$M =round\left(\sqrt[3]{6N-5\sqrt[3]{6N}}\right)$$
If $6N-5M=M^3$, and $M$ is odd, then I think $N$ is in the sequence.